# Need help remove part from url

Tags: php, url, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to get part from url, i know lots tutorial in this website
but i'm still unable to get it...

this sample url :

```
https://www.domain.com/want-to-keep-35/?idku=rbxbbgh3dKqn
```

I only need this part only from that url, without domain, slash and end url

```
want-to-keep-35
```

already try this code :

```
preg_replace('|https?://www\.[a-z\.0-9]+|i', '', $serp);
```

but not working. let me know if anyone in here can help me and thanks

Comment: Why not Zoid^H^H^H [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url)? (And `preg_replace()`, btw, does not update the passed variable, it *returns* the modified string.)

Comment: _"I only this part..."_ I'm confused, do you want to remove that part or get that part?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's that simple, you may use the following simple approach to get what you want:

```
$url = 'https://www.domain.com/want-to-keep-35/?idku=rbxbbgh3dKqn';
$re = '#https://www\..*?\..*?/(.*?)/#i';

preg_match($re, $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // want-to-keep-35
```

Comment: So, I understand everything else, but what does the `#` do here? Or more specifically, how it differs from `/pattern/`? I'm suspecting that it's just a deliminator and you can specify any deliminator you want.

Comment: @BrianCohan Of course, the `#` is a cute, little & harmless delimiter :)

Comment: I have learned something new today. The delimiter and how to use `(`pattern`)` to pick out parts of the match.

Comment: @BrianCohan It's so nice, you can read more about [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php#regexp.reference.delimiters) and [subpatterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php#regexp.reference.subpatterns) regarding the regular expressions :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use two patterns and run them in succession, you will be able to eliminate the first part and then the second part.

pattern 1 will find http or https and then the ://. Then it will read everything that is not a slash until the first slash effectively removing the domain from the url. Finally, it will lump in the the slash you don't want.

pattern 2 will take from a string starting with `want-to...` and find the first slash and everything after it.

```
$url = "https://www.domain.com/want-to-keep-35/?idku=rbxbbgh3dKqn";
$pattern1 = "/https?\:\/\/[^\/]+\//";
$pattern2 = "/\/.*/";
$url = preg_replace($pattern1, '', $url);
$url = preg_replace($pattern2, '', $url);
echo $url;
```

yields

```
want-to-keep-35
```

You can also pass in an array of patterns and it will evaluate them in order

```
$url = "https://www.domain.com/want-to-keep-35/?idku=rbxbbgh3dKqn";
$patterns = array("/https?\:\/\/[^\/]+\//", "/\/.*/");
$url = preg_replace($patterns, '', $url);
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.domain.com/want-to-keep-35/?idku=rbxbbgh3dKqn';

$parsedURL = parse_url($url);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(parse_url($url));
echo "</pre>";


$result = trim($parsedURL['path'], '/');
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only **if you know the domain name**, why not simply use:

```
$url = 'https://www.domain.com/want-to-keep-35/?idku=rbxbbgh3dKqn';
$keep = explode("https://www.domain.com/", $url);
$keep2 = explode("/", $keep[0]);
```

$keep[0] will contain 'want-to-keep-35/?idku=rbxbbgh3dKqn'

$keep2[0] will contain 'want-to-keep-35'